# Is this a working treatment for gray hair?

Tags: cosmetics, melanin, hair-color, pigment, melanocytes

I saw this product([link](http://lucasmeyercosmetics.com/en/products/product.php?id=127)) for restoring color to gray hair and the news articles about it([link](https://www.happi.com/contents/view_live-from-shows/2018-04-13/reverse-the-gray-iff-lucas-meyer-has-found-a-way)) that claim it stimulates melanin synthesis and hair pigmentation, But I am a bit skeptical about it so I searched about the active ingredient of this product palmitoyl tetrapeptide-20 and found that there was recent research about it for treating gray hair([link](https://www.jidonline.org/article/S0022-202X(17)32112-7/fulltext),[another link](https://www.jidonline.org/article/S0022-202X(18)31627-0/fulltext)) and most of the scientists behind this research are indeed from the company behind this product. 
So this is real? its actually restore hair color to gray hair?.

Comment: +1 for doing your homework and noticing that the only research available was authored by the company that makes the product. If you did a thorough search of the literature I'm not sure that anyone is going to have better information.